# TCP Listener connection is closed before acknowledgement/response can be sent

Tags: vb.net, tcp, client, response

I am writing a TCP listener (server) that needs to receive messages and send back an acknowledgement. Pretty basic stuff. There are literally dozens of examples out there, including MSDN, from which I copied much of my code. I can receive the message no problem. The problem comes when I try to send back the response. The sending client (Corepoint HL7 engine) reports the following error:

> The connection was closed before a response was received

I have tested my service with my own TCP sending test app (written using code copied from MSDN) and it works. But when I receive messages from Corepoint, the response does not go back.

Below is my code. Does anyone have any idea why the NetworkStream.Write method is not actually sending the data (or why the client is not receiving it)? I've tried every idea I've found in other posts that are similar to my problem, and nothing is working. Am I doing something wrong, or is something wrong in the configuration of Corepoint?

```
Sub Main()
   listenThread.Start()
End Sub

Private serverSocket As TcpListener
Dim listenThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ListenForClients))

Private Sub ListenForClients()
   Dim port As Int32 = '(pick a port #)
   Dim localIP As IPAddress = 'enter your IP

   serverSocket = New TcpListener(localIP, port)
   serverSocket.Start()

   While True  'blocks until a client has connected to the server
      Dim client As TcpClient

      If serverSocket.Pending Then
         client = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient
         'tried these 2 settings with no effect
         'client.NoDelay = True     
         client.Client.NoDelay = True

         ProcessIncomingMessageSocketTCPClient(client)   'I was doing this in a separate thread but temporarily kept it on this thread to eliminate threading as the possible cause (but no luck)
         client.Close()
      Else
         Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) 'wait 1 second and poll again            
      End If
   End While
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessIncomingMessageSocketTCPClient(ByRef objClient As TcpClient)

   Dim strMessageText As String
   Dim clientStream As NetworkStream
   Dim msgBuffer(4096) As Byte
   Dim numberOfBytesRead As Integer
   Dim strChunk As String
   Dim strCompleteMessage As New Text.StringBuilder
   Dim sendBytes As Byte()

   clientStream = objClient.GetStream()

   Do
      numberOfBytesRead = clientStream.Read(msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length)
      strChunk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msgBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead)
      strCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", strChunk)
   Loop While clientStream.DataAvailable
   strMessageText = strCompleteMessage.ToString

   sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("I received a message from you")
   clientStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
   objClient.Close() 'tried it with and without this line

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried not closing the client in your polling loop?  usually this behavior is because you've intentionally closed the connection (or ended the program) before actually getting the data from the connection.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. It made no difference

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that nothing is wrong with my code. The TCP was and is working correctly. This application is an HL7 listener and I was missing the MLP wrapping around my ACK. As soon as I added that, the sending application accepted my ACK and all is good.